# Throw "IDX10223: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired." when working Azure AD with Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm integrating the "Microsoft Azure AD" to our Asp.NET web projects, all works fine following the guide shown at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapp-dotnet/, even I deploy it to IIS 8.5. However, thing goes bad when I keep the page in Chrome for one night and try to access it again the next morning by doing a refresh, it runs into the exception:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
IDX10223: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired.
ValidTo: '05/19/2016 10:45:59'
Current time: '05/19/2016 21:46:31'.
```

Anybody experienced the same problem? How can I refresh the Token? I tried doing Signout directly and changed the public address, but all doesn't work.

BTW, I did some research, but all mentioned is that it has been resolved in "AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server" instead of "Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect".

Comment: Having the same issue. How did you get to resolve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar "IDX10222" error, after setting the windows time zone to automatic and rebooting the system was able to sign in.

Additionally had to add "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;" to be able to see date and times here - The token is not yet valid. ValidFrom: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII ]', Current time: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII ]'.

Answer (score 5):

I am having that same problem, Someone on the git here saying its bug https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server/issues/191 but I think its related to your machine time because OpenidConnect OAuth token is valid for 1 hour. If your machine time settings is wrong then it behave like this. You can change the time try to test this. please clear your browser cookies too so framework not use older cookies.

Comment: I just had the same problem with IDX10222 - "Lifetime validation failed. The token is not yet valid".  I had to sync my machine's time with time servers, which forced the VM times to sync as well, after which I no longer experienced the error.

Comment: I too am having the same problem but am running in an Azure instance.  The only thing I can think of that has changed is we switched the "Always On" setting on the services to help with cold starts.

Comment: I have just had the same thing and realised my system clock hadn't synced since the clocks went forward for summer so was showing as 9am rather than 10am

Answer (score 4):

In our case, this was a `Docker` container issue. After leaving the PC to hibernate, combined with a `Docker` update of some kind, equalled the `Docker` container stack in time. A `Docker` cleanup and a machine reboot, sorted it.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, my date/time settings of Windows Pro 10 (the device I was using to login) was not set automatic.
Setting it to get date/time automatic solved the issue.

Comment: if you change your windows timezone you may get `401` . in my case; i change and equalize my `windows` timezone and `genymotion` timezone. Problem Solved.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the Identity Server's time was ahead then my machine where I was consuming the service. After setting correct time, you can also try clearing browser cookies.

Comment: And how did you do so?